# Homogeneous linear system with more variables than equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, homogeneous-equation

I need to proof the following:
When a homogeneous linear system has more variables than equations it has infinite solutions. 
I don't know where to start! 
Thank you for your help

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this. First, try eliminating equations one by one ( see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)) and then you'll notice some free variables. 
Since you used matrices as tag, you should check out [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) and it's proofs.

Comment: Ok I know how to solve a system like the one I have describe, the thing is I don't know how to demonstrate it. I think the second link is broken 'cause it takes me to the first one (the Wikipedia answer)

Comment: Sorry, I meant [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

At first remember that if $x$ is a solution of an homogeneous linear system, than also $\alpha x$ is (with $\alpha \in \mathbf{R}$).

Then for example the [Gram Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) describes how to find many orthogonal solutions, and you can exploit it to prove it.